# How to open burp suite with particular configuration?

Tags: configuration, burp

**Scenario :**

I wanted logging functionality in burp, so just enabled it by going to :

> options tab --> Misc tab --> Logging

By clicking the checkbox, the logging functionality is working fine.

**My Question :**

The next time I open burp, I want the logging settings to be enabled by default. 
How should I set the options in configuration file so that I can pass it while starting burp  from terminal.

P.S 
I am using Ubuntu-14.04 (32-bit) with Burp Pro v 1.6.
There is no burp.conf file created in ubuntu.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default burp should remember your settings. You can check burp menu > remember settings

Also why don't you use save / restore state. It is very useful for changing settings easily (proxy, auth methods, logging, intercept options etc ..)

Comment: MatandDie - I tried the first option of yours. I went to "remember settings" but the problem is that it simply stores settings related to intuder, scanner, etc. It is not able to remember the logging options which is under "Misc" tab. 
---
In "save/restore" state, burp is remembering its current "state", which also considers the scope as well as targets and stuff. 
What I exactly want is that burp should start fresh with the logging functionality switched ON, which is by default switched OFF when I everytime start burp. 
I hope you are getting me. :)